# Insert a string inside of another string (without an intermediate string)

Tags: c, string

I came across this question and it asks if it's possible to write the function

```
void insert(char* M, char* T, int i)
```

that inserts the string T inside M starting from the index i, without using an intermediate string... I tried to use `realloc` but I think there's a problem when the original string M is a lot smaller than the result, my theory is that `realloc` changes the address of the string to be able to represent the new string.

For example: M="Wg"  T="ron" and i=1; the result should be M="Wrong".

I'm using the following code:

```
void insert(char* M,char* T,int i)
{
    int l;
    l=strlen(M);
    M=realloc(M,l+strlen(T)+1);

    for(int j = l-1; j >= i; j--)
    {
        M[j+strlen(T)]=M[j];
    }

    for(int j = 0;j < strlen(T); j++)
    {
        M[i+j]=T[j];
    }

    M[l+strlen(T)]='\0'; //from what i've tested the string M is correct.
}
```

and using this declaration:

```
    char *s=malloc(3);
    char *c=malloc(18);
    strcpy(s,"as");
    strcpy(c,"bcdefghijklmnopqr");
    insert(s,c,1); //this example does not work on my machine.
```

I hope this clarifies the question.

So is there a way to do it?

Comment: `man memmove` ...

Comment: If you are going to use `realloc` a) the passed pointer must have been a dynamic allocation (not, for example, an array), and 2) you must `return` the reallocated pointer for the caller.

Comment: From the edit, you won't be able to either reallocate, or to insert anything, from `M = "Wg"`.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that it's a dynamic allocation in my code ,that was just an illustration of the insertions, so with a void function we cannot do it ?

Comment: @RafikBouloudene it's possible with that `insert` prototype if the responsibility of memory management is on the caller. Please clarify what part of it you're having trouble with.

Comment: @YakovGalka So if i understood correctly there's isn't a methode to be sure that it will work 100%, it depends if there's enough space to allocate new characters while keeping the address of the first element untouched ?

Comment: asked another way, are you having trouble allocating enough space for the combined string or the algorithm for actually combining the strings? Those are two different problems.

Comment: @yano the algorithm.

Comment: @RafikBouloudene yes; that's if you need to worry about it at all. Many C functions that deal with strings (e.g. `strcat`, `strcpy`, ...) simply assume that there's enough space available.

Comment: @RafikBouloudene: as it stands your question is about memory management. If you're having trouble with "the algorithm" (i.e. moving characters around) then edit your question accordingly: remove all the irrelevant talk about `realloc` and explain what you tried and where it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a possible implementation using `memmove`.  Explanations are in the comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insertString(char* M, const char* T, size_t index)
{
    // ASSUMES there's enough space in M for this operation
    // get the original lengths of each string
    size_t Mlen = strlen(M);
    size_t Tlen = strlen(T);

    if (index < Mlen)
    {
        // M+index+Tlen is the destination position where the remaining characters in M will start
        // M+index is the index where T will be inserted
        // Mlen-index is the remaining number of characters in M that need to move
        memmove(M+index+Tlen, M+index, Mlen-index);
        // copy the T string to the space we just created
        memcpy(M+index, T, Tlen);
        // NUL terminate the new string
        M[Mlen + Tlen] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        // simply strcat if the index falls outside the range of M
        strcat(M, T);
    }
}
```

If you're not allowed to use [`memmove`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) or [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), it's simple enough to roll your own.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P4o787j5K)

Answer (score 0):

[This isn't really an answer; it's a clarification that's too complicated for a comment.]

If you can assume that the caller looks like

```
char string[6] = "Wg";
insert(string, "ron", 1);
```

(or with the `string` array having any size greater than 5), then you can write `insert()` easily.

If you can assume that the caller looks like

```
char *string = malloc(3);
strcpy(string, "Wg");
insert(string, "ron", 1);
```

then you can almost write `insert()` using `realloc` to make the string larger, except you have no way to return the possibly-new (that is, possibly moved) value of `string`.

If the caller might look like

```
char *string = "Wg";
insert(string, "ron", 1);
```

or even

```
char *string = "Wg\0\0\0";
insert(string, "ron", 1);
```

than you definitely cannot write `insert()`, because you cannot assume that the pointed-to string is writable (and on many platforms it will not be).

So, in general, the answer is: "No".  You cannot write a general-purpose version of `insert()` that will work under all circumstances.

Note, too, that if you were to assume that the string were in malloc'ed memory and that you could use `realloc` (as in my second example), that code would *not* work for strings that were not malloc'ed (that is, it would not work for callers like my first example), and it would have no portable way of knowing, based on the pointer passed to it, whether it would be abe to safely use `realloc` or not.